# PyCharm -setting up Python debbugger extension - Compile Cython extension error

Tags: python, pycharm

I have Python 3.7. I am trying to install in PyCharm the Python debugger extension but always I get the following error compiling Cython extension.

> -NON-ZERO exit code (1): error:"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Build
>   tools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" failed
>   with exit status 2-

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Guido, welcome to SO. Please include the FULL error message you are getting when trying to install Cython extension. What you have provided is just the generic message at the end, saying that something went wrong, but it is impossible to guess what it was

Comment: Hi, I am new in PyCharm and the error message I wrote is the only one I got. If anywhere it is possible to get a FULL error message please let me know.

Comment: Almost identical error, but *exit status 2* is now *exit code 2* https://stackoverflow.com/q/76378543/10141885