# How can I install Cython on Pycharm with Windows 10 when I keep getting 'Non-zero exit code (1)' error?

Tags: python, debugging, installation, pycharm, cython

Pycharm Cython Installation
I try to install cython en Pycharm with Windows 10... but get this:

`Non-zero exit code (1): error: command 'D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2` 
[Cython Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gW7a.png)

I try to reinstall Visual Studio 2019, later 2022, Compiler tools, cython woth pip, nothing works.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply downgrading the Python version solved this for me. Had this error with 3.12, but worked fine with 3.10 Py environment.